# Why is my staffing agency pressuring me to take a training course on my own time?

Tags: training

I recently started at a company in a sales engineer type position. (I also have experience as a software developer.) It is, for now, a contract position through a staffing agency.
The project I work on uses a certain technology that I do not have much experience in, and was not a requirement for the role when I was hired. The company told me that it would be helpful if I gained expertise in the technology, and they provided an on-line certification course which the company is enrolled in and makes available to all employees including me. I was told that I could work on the course if I had free time in my regular working hours.

Two weeks into the job, I was contacted by the staffing agency, and they rather strongly pressured me to commit ten hours a week of my own time to the course. They stated that this was something that both the company and the agency wanted. But they also seemed to imply that I should not discuss this matter directly with the company, as I was employed by the staffing agency, not the company, and this was an issue outside my paid work hours at the company.

I refused to commit ten hours of my own time to the course, and told them we could discuss it again in a few weeks. While I see the value to the company and am willing to learn the technology for their sake, I do not see much value in the course or the certification in my personal career goals. (The staffing agency said it would look good on my resume, but I probably would not mention it as a job skill.)

I do not expect any adverse repercussions to my refusing to commit my time to the course. I am also confident that in three months the company will hire me directly as an employee.

My question is, why is the staffing agency pressuring me?

Comment: the site is for questions, not complaining about your employer

Answer (score 8):

The agency cares how employable you are, because they only make money when they can send you out to a client.  If you don't have the right training, you are less valuable to them.  But since their income is from time billed to their clients, they have no budget to train you on their time.

The client has no interest in paying to train you.  If you employ a contractor to work for you, you expect them to be qualified.  If I employ a plumber to install a heating system in my house, I don't expect them to go off on a course on how to install heating systems, and then add that course to their bill.

So the result is that both the agency and the client wants you to be trained, but neither wants to pay for your time doing the training.  If you're not willing to accept that, either you will miss out on contracts, or you will get paid less.

Comment: It is not true that "the client has no interest in paying to train you". The client actually said "I could work on the course if I had free time in my regular working hours".

Comment: @DJClayworth: That's probably *free* as in beer, not *free* as in available.

Answer (score 2):

`I do not see much value in the course or the certification in my personal career goals`

The company you're performing the work for uses this technology. The project you're working on uses this technology. How is learning it and taking the course not valuable to your personal career goals? Do you want to continue performing this work for this company? If so, then it would behoove your personal career goals to take the course.

There have been times when a client has asked me to take certain training courses. Several of those times I had no personal or professional interest in these courses. My only interest was in keeping the client happy and keeping my position/contract with the company. So I did as they asked and took the courses. So even though I had no direct interest in the subject of the training courses, It was in my best interest to take them.

Are you serving yourself or are you serving your client? If your client requests something of you and you refuse because you're not personally or professionally interested then you're serving yourself.

If you want to serve your client then take the course.

If you want to serve yourself then quit this assignment and find something that you find more suitable.

Comment: Did you take into account that OP has been asked to do this course in their own time?

Comment: Yes. Sometimes that's what's needed. It's about serving your clients, not yourself. Sometimes you have to give to your clients a little more than is strictly required by the contract. That is, if you're interested in creating and building long term relationships and partnerships. If you're not interested in that then refuse the client request and you'll probably never work with them again.

Comment: The OP says it's 10 hours a week of their own time. Surely the course is of a finite duration. It's not 10 hours a week for the rest of their life. This seems like a small thing to acquiesce to if it means a long term relationship with this client.

Comment: You can be a hard ass and say "This isn't in my contract." or "I have no personal or professional interest in this and I am not going to do it." and I can almost guarantee you that when this project is over the client will sever their relationship with the OP and they'll never work with the OP ever again. If the OP is OK with that then they should refuse this request.

Comment: I serve my clients, which ultimately serves me. It allows me to create long term relationships with clients that are financially beneficial to me. If I find a client request so egregious that I can't or won't fulfill it then I terminate my relationship with that client.

Comment: I have no problem with taking the course for my work with the client, and fully intend to learn the technology on my own time. (It is a widely-used open-source technology, so I can get books on it). If the client told me "We really need to you get up to speed, can you devote 10 hours a week?", I would probably say yes. My issue is with the agency wanting me to do so as a commitment to them, completely separate from the client. I get the feeling that the agency is trying to use me to somehow exploit the client.

Comment: The agency's approach was very high-pressure. First there was an e-mail on Friday afternoon. Since I was busy with work (for the client) I did not respond immediately. An hour later, the agency's rep, who had worked with me to get the job, called me. They wanted me to commit, that day, to devote my time starting next week. When I said I could not commit, an hour later the agency's head, whose name I did not know and I had never spoken to before, called me with the same pitch. It seems like my refusal to commit set off a "crisis escalation".

Comment: Right, that means the customer has contacted them and are giving them a hard time about providing them a candidate without the skills they expected.  There is a real possibility they will have to replace you with that customer if you don’t skill up.

Comment: I have added to the question that the agency told me the certification would look good on my resume. Clearly this is not something that the client would say to me. The agency also tried the "it's a course worth a thousand dollars, but they are providing it to you for free!" tack. When I rebuffed the agency by saying that frankly I would not use the certification as a selling point on my resume, the agency replied, "Well yeah, it's actually not that valuable".